# Total work done at a recursion tree level

Tags: recurrence-relation, recursion, master-theorem

In the proof of Master theorem in Dasgupta's Algorithms the author says that the total work done at a recursion tree level is

$$a^k \times O\left(\frac{n}{b^k}\right)^d$$

where $a$ is the branching factor, $k$ is the tree level, $n$ is the size of the overall problem of course, $\frac{n}{b^k}$ is the size of the subproblem on this level (the problem size is decreasing by a factor of $\frac1b$ on each level), and $O(n^d)$ is the time of combining the subproblems.

I understand that we solve the subproblems at the $k$th level in $a^k \times O\left(\frac{n}{b^k}\right)+O\left(\left[\frac{n}{b^k}\right]^d\right)$. The author apparently somehow combines the two $O$'s to come up with $a^k \times O\left(\frac{n}{b^k}\right)^d$, how exactly is it done?

There're [slides](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Erajaiswal/Summer2020-2/cse101/Slides/Week-04/rec-22.pdf) based on the book, the formula in question is on the page 10.

Comment: Your understanding seems to be wrong. Unfortunately, at present only people with access to your textbook can help. I suggest looking at alternative sources covering the master theorem, for example [this one](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/lectures/lec20-master/mm-proof.pdf). All proofs are the same.

Comment: My best guess is that you're missing a parenthesis surrounding the sum.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~rajaiswal/Summer2020-2/cse101/Slides/Week-04/rec-22.pdf is based on the textbook, slide 10

Comment: I don't see your formula there. Perhaps you didn't copy it accurately?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus it's $O\left(a^k(\frac{n}{b^k})^d\right)$ on the slide. I'm puzzled about the exponent $d$, how does it come up there?

Comment: The exponent $d$ comes from the recurrence, which has the term $O(n^d)$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, not all proofs of the master theorem are the same. E.g. the original paper by Bentley, Haken and Saxe, "A General Method for Solving Divide-and-Conquer Recurrences", ACM SIGACT News 12:3 (1980), pp 36-44 sets up a linear recurrence and solves that one, bounding the resulting sum to get the estimates.  (No, they didn't call it "master theorem".).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus so the total work at the recursion level $k$ is only the time complexity for combining the answers, i.e. $O((\frac{n}{b^k})^d)$? Why do we multiply this expression by $a^k$?

Comment: ah, I guess I found it. $O(n^d)$ is the amount of work done in identifying further subproblems and combining their answers. Hence it's multiplied by the subproblems' number at the level.

Comment: >is the amount of work done
for each subproblem